# Использование Google Maps в Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли использовать API Google Карт для отображения конкретных ближайших магазинов на карте? Вкратце: есть мобильное приложение с Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps. В зависимости от местоположения пользователя нужно нанести метки на карту. Но дело в том, что сама карта GoogleMap пуста, на ней есть метки, но в них не содержится какая-либо информация. Подскажите пожалуйста что-нибудь по этому поводу, может быть есть какие-то другие библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

так же использую Google Maps Api в своём приложении и на сколько мне известно, такой функционал недоступен на данный момент. Вы можете сами получить геопозиции нужных вам локаций и добавить пины на карту. Пины можно как угодно кастомизировать и взаимодействовать с ними.